# ViewState, Session and StateServer

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms, viewstate

I have a complicated, very involved `ASP.NET` WebForm with a large `ViewState`. Currently, to lower impact in the browser (by shrinking the __VIEWSTATE hidden input field), I use a `PageAdapter` and `SessionPageStatePersister` to store the `ViewState` within the `Session`.

However, I want to change my session mode from `InProc` to `StateServer`, so that I can both lower  my RAM usage and avoid site restart and application pool recycling issues. Will I need to pull the ViewState back out of the Session? Or can it remain as is?

In the future, I'll want to load balance, also, but I heard that I could just use "sticky sessions", so that might not force me into StateServer.

NOTE: I'm currently using `.NET 2.0` (Integrated), but I'm open to updating that.

Comment: You should have no problems as ViewState is serializable. However, I'd urge you to read Scott Hanselman's view on this - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx - we used HttpCompression rather effectively on pages with large ViewStates and so avoided any session memory costs. Sticky sessions will just ensure the user goes to a single server; if you are running out of memory today, then they wont help - they can just help solve problems where you have to otherwise distribute state if a user is able to go to different servers with each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SessionPageStatePersister` stores your Viewstate in the Session object *wherever your Session happens to be stored*. It's completely agnostic about whether your session is InProc, SQL or StateServer, it should just keep working without you having to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few other options I would look into before going that route...

The first thing I would look into is ViewState compression, which can reduce the size of the ViewState by up to 60%. Telerik offers a good compression module, which you can find [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/09-02-27/optimization-tip-radcompression-for-viewstate.aspx)

Secondly, you can set a max length on the ViewState field, which will force ASP.NET to divide the ViewState across multiple hidden fields. This usually yields better page performance. You can set the `PageStateFieldLength` in the `web.config` like this:

```
<pages maxPageStateFieldLength="100"></pages>
```